# Hermite interpolation - I have an answer, but don't know why does it actualy work.

Tags: numerical-methods, hermite-polynomials

I was asked to use Hermite Interpolation to find an interpolating polynomial of a degree at most $5$ that satisfies the conditions:

|  | $x = 0$ | $x = 1$ | $ x= 3$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $f(x) = $ | $1$ | $3$ | $1$ |
| $f'(x) = $ | $0$ | $3$ |  |
| $f''(x) = $ | $6$ |  |  |

And to **find the value of a first derivative of that polynomial at $x = 4$ (described below as $b_2$) without calculating the whole derivative f'(x).**

Now I know how how to do the first part. It's the second one that bothers me (bolded). In a hint I was told to write 2 values of $x = 4$ 'at the bottom of the pyramid' (see the scheme below) and to use backward reasoning (from top of the pyramid to the bottom) since I know that the degree of the polynomial is at most 5 (so at the very top of the pyramid there will be only zeros). I got a scheme show below (by Hermite Interpolation, with notation as in Wikipedia):

$$\begin{array}{lllll}
x = 0 & f(x) = 1\\
&&0\\
x = 0 & f(x) = 1&&3\\
&&0&&-1\\
x = 0 & f(x) = 1&&2&&0\\
&&2&&-1&&0\\
x = 1 & f(x) = 3&&1&&0\\
&&3&&-1&&a_6\\
x = 1 & f(x) = 3&&-2&&a_5\\
&&-1&&a_4&&b_6\\
x = 3 & f(x) = 1&&a_3&&b_5\\
--- &&a_2&&b_4\\
x = 4 & f(x) = a_1&&b_3\\
&&b_2\\
x = 4 & f(x) = b_1\\
\end{array}$$

I know that:
$$0 = \frac{a_6 - 0}{4-0}$$
$$0 = \frac{b_6 - a_6}{4-0}$$
and so on.

And it works! I got $b_2 = -24$. It is the correct answer (I know by calculating the whole derivative). But my question is **how?** How does the algorithm work if I didn't 'provide an information that I want to calculate the value of first derivative at $x = 4$' let's say. So why is it calculated at $x = 4$ (and not e. g. at $x = 10$)?

Additional information:
The polynomial is: $1+3x^2 -x^3$, derivative is: $6x-3x^2$